# How to fadeIn element on scrolling to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have these elements:

```
<div class="item">First Item</div>
<div class="item">Second Item</div>
<div class="item">Third Item</div>
<div class="item">Fourth Item</div>
```

I want to show the first one of them when the page loads so i'm using :

```
    $(".item:not(:eq(0))").fadeOut();
```

Then when I scroll to the next element that element I scrolled to  should `fadeIn()`

How to achieve that ?

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: @peter if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If not please write in the comments why or edit your question to make your problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of the elements you can use: `$(window).scrollTop()`

This will give you the current "amount of scroll". If you add than the height of the window you will get the position from the bottom border of the window.

This you can compare it with the position of the element `$(item).offset().top`,
so if the bottom border of the window is bigger than the position of the element (the element is visible on the screen) you have to do the animation.

The animation is done with css. So you just have to add / remove a class to animate your element. You can remove it with e.g. `m[1].classList.remove("fade");`

See my example below. You can modify it like you need it, I hope you get the idea.

```js
function fadeIn(){

  var m = document.getElementsByClassName('item1');
  var windowBot = getCurrentScroll();
  
  $(m).each(function() {
    if (windowBot >= getItemScroll(this) ) {
      if(!this.classList.contains('fade')){
        this.className += " fade";
       }
   } 
    });
}

// returns the current position of the bottom border of the window
// 70 is the distance to the bottom window border that the element must have before it appears
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 70;
}

// returns the current position of the item
function getItemScroll(item){
  return $(item).offset().top;
}
```

```css
.item, .item1{
  position: relative;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

.item1{
    opacity:0;
}

.fade {
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onscroll="fadeIn()">
  <div class="item">First Item</div>
  <div class="item1">Second Item</div>
  <div class="item1">Third Item</div>
  <div class="item1">Fourth Item</div>
</body>
```